# Форматирование кода в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

я ввожу в редакторе `p.class` - должно при каких-то сочетаниях клавиш вылезать `<p class="class"></p>`,вопрос при каких?

Comment: `tab` нажмите и будет вам счастие. очевидно будет зависеть от типа файла, в котором вы пишите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этим занимается плагин [Emmet](https://emmet.io/), который по умолчанию включен в новых версиях PHPStorma.  Более детальную информацию по работе с Emmet, можете посмотреть [тут](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 1):

За это отвечает настройка **Live Template**, и для преобразования используется **Tab**

Comment: возможно, я  ошибаюсь, это настройка отвечает за подсказку кода... ( то есть ты вводишь "subs" тебе выдают "substr". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8vX3GcWK4U